# cannot get value from a cell in libreoffice 6.4.3.2 basic

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I am new to libreoffice basic, i have experience with VBA but this libreoffice is different.

I just want to get cell value but it always return zero value to me while the actuall cell can be text or number.

Here is a partial of my simple code.

Sub test_moved()

```
Dim Doc As Object
'worksheet
Dim sh_village As Object
Dim sh_cbc As Object

sh_village = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getActiveSheet()
'sh_village = Doc.Sheets.getByName("VillageFinal")
'sh_village = Doc.Sheets(1)

Msgbox(sh_village.getCellrangeByName("B2").getValue())
Msgbox(sh_village.getCellrangeByName("B2").Value)   
Msgbox(sh_village.getCellByPosition(1,1).Value)

msgbox("The process is completed.")
```

End Sub

Do we need to do prior task before start coding?

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly for numeric values. However, for strings, including strings that look like a number, it will display `0` because there is no numeric value.

What you probably want instead is:

```
MsgBox(sh_village.getCellRangeByName("B2").getString())
```

Also check out *Format -> Cells -> Number* to see how the data is displayed in the cell. And be on the lookout for a single quote at the front of the value in the formula bar (for example `'42`), because that means it is a string. Delete the quote to make it a number.

> i have experience with VBA but this libreoffice is different.

Yes, LibreOffice Basic is a different language from VBA and the LibreOffice API is very different from the MS Office API. Knowing that will help you use it more effectively. If possible, avoid `Option Compatible`, because it won't fix most problems and will only muddy the waters.